# Python 3.6.2 not running loops over a single value

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In my code I have implemented a loop where the lower and upper bounds are variable, and it can happen that lower and upper bound are the same. In this case, Python skips the loop.

```
for i in range(low_, high_):
    print(i)
```

Is there a way to fix this in the definition of the loop?

Comment: what do you want? I mean you want that if low and hight are the same the loop run once?

Comment: what do you want to fix here exactly? what should it do when it is e.g., `for i in range(2, 2):`?

Comment: The way `range()` works, it starts at the first number but never gives the last. So, if you only want to run once, you would say range(x, x+1).  When both the start and stop numbers are the same, the loop will not execute.
If you do want the loop to run at least once, then add +1 to the second number, like in my range(x, x+ 1) above. But you may need to adjust what happens inside the loop as a result.  Maybe just calling `range(low_, high_ + 1)` will do what you need...

Comment: If `high_ = low_ + 1`, the loop runs once. Do you really want the same result when they're equal?

Answer (score 5):

yes, when `low == high`, the loop does not enter.

Loops run from `start` to the inclusion of `(end - 1)`; it is therefore entirely normal behavior

In the case where `low == high`, you must test to print the low. (credits to @Michael_heath for catching a mistake in the comments)

```
for i in range(low_, high_):
    print(i)
if low_ == high_:
    print(low_)
```

Comment: `low_, high_ = 2, 4` outputs `2 3 2`. Your loop has no break to skip the else.

Comment: Ouch, that is true... Then, a `for else` cannot be used, we have to test for `low == high` to print. Thank you for catching this.

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
for i in range(low_, high_ + 1):
    print(i)
```

It sounds like you want your loop to start at low_ and get to high_, even if they're the same. So adding the extra '+ 1' should get you what you want.

In general a loop only gets to one less than the second value.  If you want to hit that value, adding the extra one should do the trick.